# Finding PGF of a sum of Poisson variables, where the summation is also a poisson value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

$ B \sim Pois(7) $

$ C_{i} \sim Pois(10)$, where all $ B, C_{0}, C_{1}, ... $ are independent

I have a random variable A that is expressed as

$ A = \sum^{B}_{i=0} C_{i} $

Now I want to find the distribution of A, or if it cannot be expressed as a distribution, just the pgf.

Here is my working so far:

$ G_{A}(z) = \mathbb{E}(z^{A})$

$ G_{A}(z) = \mathbb{E}(z^{\sum^{B}_{i=0} C_{i}})$

$ G_{A}(z) = \mathbb{E}(z^{C_{0} + C_{1} + ... + C_{B}})$

$ G_{A}(z) = \mathbb{E}(z^{C_{0}} \cdot z^{C_{1}} \cdot...\cdot z^{C_{B}})$

By virtue of independence

$ G_{A}(z) = \mathbb{E}(z^{C_{0}}) 
\cdot \mathbb{E}(z^{C_{1}}) 
\cdot...\cdot \mathbb{E}(z^{C_{B}})$

$ G_{A}(z) = G_{C_{0}}(z) 
\cdot G_{C_{1}}(z) 
\cdot...\cdot G_{C_{B}}(z) $

Since $ C_{i} \sim Pois(10) $, $ G_{C_{i}}(z) =  e^{10(z-1)} $

$ \therefore 
G_{A}(z) = (e^{10(z-1)})^{B} $

I feel as if I am on the right track, but I'm unsure how to continue.

Comment: You're close... from total law of expectation, you have $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{E}\left(z^{C_0}\times \dots\times z^{C_B}\right)&=&\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left(z^{C_0}\times \dots\times z^{C_B}|B\right)\right) \\ &=& \mathbb{E}\left(\left(e^{10(z-1)}\right)^B\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$ Can you continue?

Comment: Honestly no, I understand how you have gotten to that step and I did contemplate it before but I couldn't work out how to move forward with it.

Comment: Use LOTUS to continue. $$\mathbb{E}\left(\left(e^{10(z-1)}\right)^B\right)=\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}\left(e^{10(z-1)}\right)^b\mathbb{P}(B=b)$$

Comment: Ah, I see thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the PGF, you have to use the law of total expectation:

$$\mathcal P_A(t) = \mathbb E[t^A] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[t^A \mid B]] = \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[ \prod_{i=1}^B t^C_i \mid B \right] \right] = \mathbb E\left[ \prod_{i=1}^B \mathbb E[t^{C_i}]\right] = \mathbb E[\mathcal P_C(t)^B].$$  Since the PGF of a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda$ is $$\mathcal P_C(t) = e^{\lambda(t-1)},$$ it follows that
$$\mathcal P_A(t) = \mathbb E[e^{\lambda (t-1)B}] = \mathcal M_B(\lambda(t-1)),$$ where  $\mathcal M_B$ is the moment-generating function of $B$:  $$\mathcal M_B(t) = \mathbb E[e^{tB}] = e^{\rho (e^t - 1)},$$ where $\rho$ is the rate parameter of $B$.  Thus $$\mathcal P_A(t) = e^{\rho (e^{\lambda(t-1)} - 1)}$$ for the choice $\lambda = 10$, $\rho = 7$.  One is naturally led to ask whether this PGF corresponds to a Poisson distribution, but it is clearly not.

Can we compute the PMF of $A$?  Well, recalling that the sum of IID Poisson variables is also Poisson, specifically $$C_1 + \cdots + C_B \mid B \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda B),$$ we would need to write
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[A = a] &= \sum_{b=0}^\infty \Pr[A = a \mid B = b]\Pr[B = b] \\
&= \sum_{b=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda b} \frac{(\lambda b)^a}{a!} e^{-\rho} \frac{\rho^b}{b!} \\
&= \frac{e^{-\rho} \lambda^a}{a!} \sum_{b=0}^\infty (e^{-\lambda}\rho)^b \frac{b^a}{b!}.
\end{align}$$
The function $$f_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^n \frac{z^k}{k!}$$ obeys the recursion
$$z f'_n(z) = f_{n+1}(z)$$ which can be used to recursively compute successive values of the PMF.